# OWL How to make class C equivalent to class A union Class B in protege

Tags: java, owl, protege

I have 3 class :
Class A : tall
Class B : big
Class C : Superman

a person can be instance of A or instance of B of instance of both of them. when a person is instance of A and B so she is an instance of C.

I put the class C equivalent to "A and B" and i have created an individual who is tall and big.

When i start my reasoner my individual is only in the class C. but since that C = A union B, my individual must be an instance of A and B and C. so how can i make him an instance of A and B and C ?

Comment: Your whole question contains contradicting statements: **but since that C = A union B** and **I put the class C equivalent to "A and B"** . What is correct now?

Comment: `C EquivalentTo A and B` -> individuals of `C` belong to `A` **and** `B`

Comment: `C EquivalentTo A or B` -> individuals of `C` belong to `A` **or** `B` - thus, a reasoner can't infer to which of the classes A or B - even both is possible

Comment: C respresent the intersection of A and B

Comment: And what does not work now?

Comment: the reasonner says that my individual is just an instance of C. he must says that he is instance of A, B and C ( because C is the intersection of A and B )

Comment: Wait a minute. The individual is assigned to which class by yourself?

Comment: As a side note, Protege doesn't show all inferences, especially not for ABox axioms which can be too many and slow the GUI. If you go to the DL Query tab, and query for "Instances" of `A`, the individual will be shown, thus, the reasoner works as expected.

Comment: the individual is assigned to A and B by myself

Comment: And you said that `C` is inferred by the reasoner. So again, what is the problem?

Comment: yes he is inferred and it's what i want. but i want to know why he says that my individual is just instance of C. before being instance of C, he is instance of A and instance of B. so i expect my reasonner to say that my individual is instance of A, B and C

Comment: I can **not** follow you. What means "reasoner says"? You're using Protege, or not? And you have three classes `A, B, C` and an axiom `C EquivalentTo A and B`. And you have an individual `x` assigned to `A` and `B`. When you run the reasoner, `C` will be inferred. I don't understand how you're using the reasoner. Which view do you use?

Comment: i am using protege and you are correct, that's it

Comment: the only problem is why A  and B don't contain my individual when i start the reasonner. he is only instance of C

Comment: And that's what I don't understand from your description. You have already assigned the individual to the classes `A` and `B`. It is explicitly done by yourself, no inference is necessary. Can you share a screenshot such that I understand which tab/view in Protege you mean?

Comment: here is my ontology : https://drive.google.com/file/d/17awXDM6zg4co8joHIeFJpPzyEHtQGBTk/view?usp=sharing   my Class A is : Intensif, B is Captive and C is Otaku. you can try it with the individual 'salt' for example

Comment: `salt` is **not** assigned to class `Captive` and `Intensif`. I was asking you several times if that's the case, and you said, "yes".

Comment: None of the individuals is assigned to any class at all. They only have data property assertions.

Comment: Oh yes I am sorry. It's the reasonner who must detect that according to his data properties. And if he is instance of captive and also instance of intensitf so he is otaku. The reasonner detect otaku bust he don't say that he is instance of captive and intensif by the way

Comment: That's what I already told you. Protege doesn't show all inferences, especially not those redundant. It can be to critical for the GUI to show all the individuals the class hierarchy upwards, that's the only reason why you can'T see it in the GUI. But as I said, it doesn't matter. The reasoner is doing everything as expected. You can check this with the DL Query tab. Enter `Intensif`, select "Instances" and click on "Execute". The individuals belonging to the class will be shown here

Answer (score 2):

`A and B` represents the intersection. To get the union you have to have `A or B`.

Comment: i am sorry i want the intersection so i did C equivalent to "A and B". my problem is that the reasonner says that my individual is only instance of C ( but he is instance of A, B and C )